# Pandas GroupBy values within a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[CSV File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xSCS2gRW94Tpgs-R0pWIgEvtKMEiR8kE/view?usp=sharing)
I have csv file imported as a dataframe on Python pandas and wish to take 2 columns clean the data and produce a Boxplot.
The selected columns are both quantitative so I wish to group all the values in one of the columns and make it qualitative of sorts.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

bottle['Depthm'] = pd.to_numeric(bottle['Depthm'], errors='coerce')
bottle['R_TEMP'] = pd.to_numeric(bottle['R_TEMP'], errors='coerce')

df = pd.DataFrame(bottle)

df['R_TEMP']=df['R_TEMP'].replace(0, np.nan)
df['Depthm']=df['Depthm'].replace(0, np.nan) 

df1 = df.groupby(['Depthm', 'R_TEMP'])
print(df.groupby(['Depthm', 'R_TEMP']).groups)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Depthm':['0-10','10-20','20-30','30-40','40-50']})

bins= [0,10,20,30,40,50]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df["0-10"], np.arange(0, 10, 10))).sum()
print(df['DepthGroup'])

%matplotlib inline
sns.boxplot(x ='R_TEMP', y =['DepthGroup'], grid = False, data = df)
plt.xlabel('Reported Temperature')
plt.ylabel('Depth group')
```

I am a first year uni student and am genuinely at a loss on how to solve this issue after browsing both the web and my notes. This is my first time sending a quesiton in so I apologise for my formatting and any help is appreciated.

The expected result is something such as this:

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbwMW.png)

Comment: Can you provide your data?

Comment: Yes I have it hyperlinked now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import seaborn as sns
df['g'] = pd.cut(df['Depthm'], [0,10,20,30,40,50])
ax = sns.boxplot(x=df['g'], y=df['R_TEMP'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I have understood a good part of your reasoning and syntax here, it's not quite the graph I expected but this is good step towards it.

Comment: Look at the answer now.

Comment: The plot produced is not changing. I'm not sure if you missed a change you made.